# Mysql, In my matrix, an index is not used

Tags: mysql

given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE  `matrix` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city1_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `city2_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timeinmin` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `distancem` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `OWNER` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `city12_index` (`city1_id`,`city2_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `city21_index` (`city2_id`,`city1_id`),
  KEY `city1_index` (`city1_id`),
  KEY `city2_index` (`city2_id`),
  KEY `ownerIndex` (`OWNER`),
  CONSTRAINT `PK_city_city1` FOREIGN KEY (`city1_id`) REFERENCES `city` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `PK_city_city2` FOREIGN KEY (`city2_id`) REFERENCES `city` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5118409 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

there are very huge amount of datas.

This SQL runs very fast:

```
select count(*) from city_matrix where owner=1
```

since there is index on "`owner`"

```
select count(*) from city_matrix where owner=1 order by id
```

this also runs very fast. But this:

```
select count(*) from city_matrix where owner=1 order by city1_id
```

requires some seconds, BUT there is index on `city1_id` too!

The explain tells this:

1, 'SIMPLE', 'city_matrix', '', 'ref', 'ownerIndex', 'ownerIndex', '4', 'const', 169724, 100.00, ''

Comment: How fast does this run - `select count(*) from city_matrix use index (city1indexname) where owner=1 order by city1_id` where we have given an index hint to the query? Then, do `create index idx_city_matrix_city1_owner on city_matrix(owner, city1_id)` and run your query again without the hint?

Comment: forcing index wont help, same slowness.

Comment: Did composite index on owner and city1_id help?

Comment: Im adding this index, but takes a while :)

Comment: CCOOOOOLLLL works like a charm!

Comment: Excellent. Let me add this as an answer with some more description

Comment: Very simple.. your city id is referncekey it means u can use inner join... because cityid in his table should be a primary key and primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question. MySQL determines the right index based on many different cases. Its main goal is to find the most suitable index that can retrieve the data fast.

```
select count(*) from city_matrix where owner=1 order by id
```

In this query, MySQL determined that `where owner=1` reduced the results to a small enough number that ordering by ID was relatively easy. For example, if ID is also a key (primary/unique/index), which I suspect it is, MySQL could take advantage of ID for sorting.

In case of this:

```
select count(*) from city_matrix where owner=1 order by city1_id
```

MySQL can still filter out all the records for owner but will take time to shuffle all the city1_id data so that you receive sorted result. Since it took time, `show processlist` during that time could have showed you that the query was reordering data.

To help MySQL do the job faster, we can use something called a `covering index`. Covering index has all fields used in the query so that MySQL just has to read through the index to get you the data without having to touch the underlying table. A composite index on owner and city1_id will help MySQL use one single index to filter data, and that same index again to sort data and then do a count on it.

So, let's create the covering index:

```
create index idx_city_matrix_city1_owner on city_matrix(owner, city1_id)
```

As you noticed, MySQL took some time to make the index and once the index was ready, it could zip through data pretty quickly to give you counts.

EDIT: It is important to note that when you do count(*) like the statements about do, you don't need ordering. The resultset is scalar - just one value. Ordering by any field does not impact your count. For example, count all the fruits on the table will give you the same results as count all the fruits on the table ordered by its size.

Answer (score 1):

The process for retrieval and index application is as follows:

The intermediate result which is retrieved by MySQL for the key owner is "stored" in a temporary table (either in memory or on disk depending on the size of the result).

Based on histogram data on the intermediate result an index can be applied. If the data is not unique enough, the index can be discarded as not useful (for example: There are only 5 cities in this 169k results).

**Work around**:

- Apply the index with a hint: This is considered poor since it can lead to unwanted index use speeding up one query and slowing down the next one (Yes, an index can make a query slower);
- Create a multi column index which contains both the owner and city1_id.

**One last remark**

An `order by` on a `COUNT(*)` always slows down everything since the `order by` does not change anything of your result.